# Constraints when writing Python class

Tags: python, django

I`m using Python 3.5.2 and Django 1.11 using SQLite

I faced situation where i want to name my model **Class** with certain name, but with **different names** I get **different results** in manage.py migration regarding **ForeignKeys**

Example from shell:

modules.py

```
from django.db import models


class Place(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Running python3 manage.py makemigrations post

```
Migrations for 'post':
  post/migrations/0001_initial.py   
    - Create model Choice
    - Create model Place
    - Add field question to choice'
```

When renaming class Choice into in example "Rating":

```
from django.db import models


class Place(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Rating(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Output of migration attempt:

```
Migrations for 'post':
  post/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Place
    - Create model Rating
```

You might notice that foreign key implementation disappeared. I`ve triple checked it everywhere. Tried with new projects. Stuck with this for a few days. Is there any class naming restrictions or some sort of a bug?

Have a nice holidays, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, in both cases the foreign key is created.

In the first case, the `Choice` model is created first, and since `Place` doesn't exist yet, it can't create the foreign key at the time the model is created. Therefore it is added later in a separate step after the `Place` model is created.

In the second case, the `Place` model is created first, so the foreign key can be created in the `CreateModel` operation for `Rating`.

Ideally, both cases would produce the second output whenever possible, as it contains less steps, but that optimisation hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So basically in the end both queries gives me the same final result in database model and relationship?

Comment: Yes, the end result is the same. The first case just delays the creation of the foreign key field until the target model (`Place`) exists.